# how to get back jquery ajax request sent data on xhr error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have many jquery ajax requests, sent with one function.

```
function sendData(data){
    $.post("somepage", {"data": data}, function() {}, "json")
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        sendData(***previuoslySentData***);
    });
}
sendData(1);
sendData(2);
sendData(3);
...
```

as you can see, when a request fails I want to be able to send the request again with previously sent data.
**how can I get back sent data on xhr error?**
I thought it should be in xhr but I couldn't find anything.
I'm also interested in any other solution for this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the `data` still be available as the `data` parameter passed to the function? So: `sendData(data);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've wrapped your AJAX request in a function of its own, you're effectively creating a new closure, which means that the `data` variable that you accept as an input parameter, will be still be usable in your `.fail` callback.

Comment: @Thomas and Hedlund, oh! I never thought it could work this way, interesting! and thank you guys :)

Comment: @Drust: Do read up on closures in javascript. They're amazing if you know them, and they'll bite you if you don't.